all connections encrypted but the database mirroring ones no
based on the picture below you can see a result of
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
nice dmv to show the current connections.
now if you look at the detail,the databasae mirroring connections are not encrypted.
question is:
should it be cause of concern?



now if you look at the detail,the databasae mirroring connections are not encrypted.

The tldr is that it's not expected to show up with any data in this DMV and the correct catalog view for this is sys.database_mirroring_endpoints with columns is_encrypted and encryption_algorithm_desc.
The sys.dm_exec_connections is originally from SQL 2005 which predates database mirroring, soap endpoints, webmethods, http endpoints, and well all the other now defunct stuff that was all the hot rage so it had to be in every product :cough, AI, cough:. The DMV was originally made for the single type of endpoint that exists, the TDS endpoint (TDS being the protocol SQL Server uses to exchange commands and data). TDS endpoints are, therefor, fully supported and work well with that DMV. Then, along came all these other endpoint types, which all had their own special configurations and options, so they got their own catalog views but didn't get folded into many of the DMVs, hence, today.
Longer story longer, there is nothing that precludes the data to be shunted into the encrypt_option column in sys.dm_exec_connections from any other endpoint, as in your question the DATABASE_MIRRORING endpoint. The whole reason it doesn't show anything for that column in the DMV is because no one took the time to make it show anything. The only implemented endpoint for that DMV is the TDS endpoint. All others will show the default values you see above in your screenshot.
Here's where it gets... weird. Given this is the expected(?) behavior since 2005 SP1 (?) when you could turn on TFs and get mirroring setup, we're at a place where changing this could be considered a breaking change. I don't know enough about who uses the DMV and what is expected, though I've answered this question so many times it seems the expected result is the actual value (if it is or isn't and the auth scheme)... though someone could argue about backwards compatibility and my god does SQL Server keep backwards compatibility at the cost of moving anything forward, so that could be a pyrrhic battle.
Anyway, yeah, use the sys.database_mirroring_endpoints DMV. Yes, endpoints even though there can only ever be a single one.

brilliant answer cheers
